# "set shiftround" doesn't work in Vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm using *MacVim*, and when trying to `set shiftround` in my `.vimrc` I get the following error:

```
E518: Unknown option:  shiftround
```

**EDIT:** *However, when I try to `:set shiftround` manually within Vim, it works and gives no errors.*

Anybody knows what is causing this? If somebody wants to view my whole `.vimrc` (perhaps something else I'm not of is the cause of this), please do:

https://github.com/oryband/dotvim/blob/master/vimrc

Comment: do you get the same error when trying to set shiftround in Vim's command line?

Comment: No, it's fine. I've added this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using MacVim 7.3, that option works for me: [vimrc link](https://github.com/pbyrne/dotfiles/blob/master/src/vimrc). Which version of MacVim are you using? Like michaelmichael asked, what happens if you try :set shiftround within the application?

Comment: I'm also using MacVim 7.3, and when trying to set this manually, it works. Very wierd. I'll add that to the question.